# Deleting files not containing double digit number and pattern in grep

Tags: regex, linux, match

The pattern below is supposed to delete all files that dont start with `1_` but instead it matches all files that don't contain `1`.

For example, it'll not match `11_xxx.sql.bz2` and `1_xxx.sql.bz2` but will match all the others correctly.

How can I ensure the pattern only matches the exact number and not any number which contains the number?

For example, i would like the script below only to not match `1_xxx.sql.bz2`

```
ls | grep -P "^[^1]+_([^_]+).+$" | xargs -d"\n" rm
```

Comment: `grep` matches the file contents, not the filenames.

Comment: I'm still confused on the question. You want to delete all files that do NOT start with `1`? Like `rm [^1]*`??

Comment: Do you want to delete all files that don't start with `1_`?

Comment: **Statuary Warning:** You must avoid parsing `ls` output.

Comment: Sorry guys ive updated the command that i'm using.
Yes David, that is correct but, but also keeping to the pattern given above. I.e. with .tar and the underscores.

Comment: @anubhava thanks for that, its only to make life easier in removing a particular set of files from my end as a dev. im not a shell guru - is this still problematic, if so how should i change it ? :)

Comment: To delete files starting with anything but `1` and ending in `.sql.bz2` you should just be able to `rm [^1]*.sql.bz2`. You can always check what it will catch with `ls - 1 [^1]*.sql.bz2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I will need to keep items without a number at the start

I suggest using `find` like this to match all files in current directory excluding those that start with `1_`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '[0-9]*' -not -name '1_*' -delete
```

If your `find` doesn't support `-delete` then use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '[0-9]*' -not -name '1_*' -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, thank you for that.
Do you have any tips as there are a few files for example: test.sql.bz2 that dont have the (number)_test.sql.bz2 pattern but i would like to keep them?

This solution seems helpful, but thats the only thing im struggling with - I will need to keep items without a number at the start :)

Comment: Great job Anubhava!

Answer (score 0):

use `grep -v` to invert the match, so you exclude files that match the pattern.

```
grep -v '^1_'
```